# Insert Task controller not executing from VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

Having a little issue. Trying to insert a task using a custom controller, and I am not getting any kind of "error" when this executes. Everything else on the page seems to work but this.

Any help would be great. Thanks.
Also I have taken out any fields that would be pulled from the page and tried to just test it by entering the variables and it didn't work.

```
 public List<Task> tasks {get; set;}
 public ID CurrentAcct = Apexpages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
 public ID CurrentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
 private String soql {get;set;}
 private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
 private Account_Plan__c AcctObj;
 private Task Ntask;


 //Other Code here for queries and constructor


   Public Pagereference AddTask(){
    String taskdate = Apexpages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().get('tdate');
    Date d = date.parse(taskdate);
    Ntask = new Task();
    Ntask.ActivityDate = date.parse('5/25/13');
    Ntask.Subject = 'This is a test';
    Ntask.OwnerId = CurrentUser;
    Ntask.WhatId = CurrentAcct;
    Ntask.Status = 'In Progress';
    Ntask.Priority = 'Normal';
    Ntask.Type = 'Call';


    try{
    insert Ntask;}
    catch (Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There was an Error! Cannot Create Task'));
    } 

    return null;
    }
```

Comment: Should you be inserting Ntask, rather than t?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I forgot to change that when I did a copy and paste from my Notepad

Comment: So no errors but the task isn't created? How are CurrentUser and CurrentAcct populated? Can you add that code?

Comment: No errors were shown. I added the CurrentUser and CurrentAcct

Comment: Sounds silly, but are you sure the method is being called from the page? Try adding a pagemessage inside the try to show that the code is running.

Comment: You are right. The code isn't running. I need to look at my VF page. -__-

Comment: If I move my comment into an answer do I get the karma? :)

Comment: instead of return null, if there are no errors, return the task record. try{
    insert Ntask; return new ApexPages.pagereference('/' + ntask.Id);}
    catch (Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There was an Error! Cannot Create Task'));return null;
    }  Also in your Page make sure you use <apex:pageMessages/> tag to display errors.

Comment: @ AlphaBravo, was this ever resolved? If so, would you post the solution or tell us whose comments led you to it?

Comment: The code was right all along. The visualforce page was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

> 1) Ensure that you are rerendering the apex:pageMessages block of your vf page from the
>   command button which is executing the AddTask method.
>   
> 2) As suggested
>   by CoryCowgill instead of **return null;** use **return new
>   pageReference('/'+Ntask.Id);**